# Soft artisans ExcelWriter Data Binding - Insert Cells Instead of Rows

Tags: officewriter

According to the article

http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/How+ExcelWriter+Inserts+Rows

ExcelWriter inserts a new row for every row in the dataset. What if my dataset has 5 columns, for each row, I want ExcelWrite just to insert 5 cells and only expand the table for those 5 columns, not the entire row. Is it doable? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe ExcelTemplate has this functionality. I believe ExcelTemplate will always insert a new row.

If you can use ExcelApplication, Import Data may work for your needs. It can be done on an area or a worksheet.

See http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW9/Area.ImportData and
http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW9/Worksheet.ImportData